# Obtaining midpoint values of grouped bars in ggplot2 barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code

```
library(ggplot2)  

test=read.table(text= 
"group fillcd percent
1 1 73.2
1 2 73.8
1 3 78.6
2 1 78.1
2 2 95.6
2 3 95.5
", header=TRUE, sep=""  )        

test$fill <- factor(test$fillcd, labels=c("XX", "EE", "BB"))
test$text=paste(test$percent,"%")

ggplot(data=test, 
  aes(group, percent, fill=fill)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
    coord_flip()+  
    geom_text(data = test, aes(y = percent, x = group, label = text ))
```

produces the following graph:
[image]

How can I obtain the midpoints of the bars in order to place a label there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean horizontal or vertical midpoint, but maybe the following example will help:

```
ggplot(data=test, 
       aes(group, percent, fill=fill)) + 
         geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(width = 0.9))+
         coord_flip()+  
         geom_text(data = test, aes(y = percent/2, x = group, label = text ), 
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

[image]

The key is `position_dodge`.